# Get-ChildItem piped to Copy-Item with rename to same directory

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item

I am trying to bulk copy/rename files of a certain extension in a specific folder to the same folder with a prefix. I am certain this is a problem with my own Powershell inexperience. I simply do not know how to set up the command.

I am trying to take all the files of extension *.mxd* within a folder and rename them from *something.mxd* to _prefix_something.mxd_

I am pretty sure the first section is fine: `Get-ChildItem *.mxd`
But I don't know how to work with `Copy-Item` well enough. My understanding is that `-Destination` is where you would put the new file name, so how do I input `("current-folder\prefix" + $_.Name + ".mxd")` ??

I am sure I am just missing a few key points to get this to work. All I am getting is a single "prefix_.mxd" file. It is the same size as the last file in the `Get-ChildItem` list. But if I bring the `foreach` loop back in, it asks for path values. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?  The doc for rename-item has a similar example.

```
dir *.mxd | copy-item -destination { 'prefix_' + $_.name } -whatif
```

Comment: Almost, though your answer would have helped had I seen it before finally finding my own answer. I need to copy and rename the files, hence copy-item instead of rename-item.

Comment: Just change rename-item -newname to copy-item -destination.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid. I have to force scriptblock with curlybraces {} instead of using parenthesis (), and I can skip the path to the current folder by starting with the prefix.